# IBM ServeRAID 5i Error on boot

Tags: raid, ibm

I am seeing this screen when I boot up:

[image: Error Screen]

It says error 2500.

I can't find any information on this. Where can I go to get more information on this problem?

Comment: As it currently stands, your question is really really bad and will be closed. I tried to do you a favor and edit it, so that it will stay open and you might get an answer. But, for some unknown reason you rolled it back to the original (bad) version. Please take a few minutes to read the [faq] and then read [ask] to get an understanding of how this site works. I'm going to roll back this edit one more time. If you choose to undo it again, I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: You sir, should not role back question the good MdMarra corrected for you. I demand satisfaction!

Comment: Whene you was edditing I was editing to, so this happened and old version stayed

Answer (score 3):

[Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ibm+serveraid+5i+error+code) is your friend.

[This](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-44287) is a list of all error codes and what action you should take to resolve the issues.

For all 2xxx codes, it says to flash the latest BIOS and firmware onto the card. If that doesn't work, replace the card.

Comment: I have upgraded firmware form 6.10.24 to 7.12.14 and no luck